# to echo a <img > tag and send the code through email+ php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php variable which contain the whole source code of image.What I want is to echo the  tag with its attributes src,height & width and send the source code of image through mail (i.e ).

```
$imagename = abc.jpg;
$concatpath = SITE_URL."/uploads/affiliatesAdv/".$imagename;
$imagesrc = '<a href="'.SITE_URL.'"><img src="'.$concatpath.'" height="200px" width="200px"></a>';
```

Now when I echo $imagesrc it displays the image. How can I show the source code instead?

Comment: `$imagesrc = '<pre>'.$imagesrc.'</pre>';`

Comment: its already in $imagesrc, so this needs to be added to the html part of the email body, I assume you are trying to send email and its coming through as plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo "<pre>";
echo $imagesrc;
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use html encoding.

Some thing like this

```
<img src="abc.jpg"/>
```

to

> `&lt;img src=&quot;abc.jpg&quot;/&gt;`

See the [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

You can try this [site](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/encode.aspx) to do it online..